# How to perform a selective groupby().count() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, count

I'm struggling with the implementation of a peculiar combination of pandas `groupby().count()` and column average computation in a script, and since I'm operating on a tight schedule I decided to ask for help here on Stack, hopefully someone will know a very pythonic and pandas-oriented solution that I can add to my baggage. All the ideas I came up with are a bit sloppy and I don't like them.

I have a pandas dataframe with 500+ rows and 80+ columns that looks like this:

```
ID  S1_R1   S1_R2   S2_R1   S2_R2  ... 
A   10      10      5       10     ...
A   9       10      0       0      ...
A   0       0       10      9      ...
B   6       10      0       0      ...
B   0       0       15      11     ...
C   5       12      0       0      ...
```

I would like to first obtain the averages of the `S*` columns. I put "S" but in reality I have longer strings which I can use in a `grep`-like operation, uptaking all those carrying the substring:

```
ID  S1      S2    ...
A   10      7.5   ...
A   9.5     0     ...
A   0       9.5   ...
B   8       0     ...
B   0       13    ...
C   8.5     0     ...
```

I would then like to assign a `True` or a `False` to each column depending on if its value inside is greater than a constant value (let's say > 0 or not):

```
ID  S1      S2      ...
A   True    True    ...
A   True    False   ...
A   False   True    ...
B   True    False   ...
B   False   True    ...
C   True    False   ...
```

Then I would like to `groupby().count()` by `ID` but considering only those samples that have `True` in the column. The outcome should be this:

```
ID   S1    S2   ...
A    2     2    ...
B    1     1    ...
C    1     0    ...
```

I am currently doing all these steps with a combination of data frame subsets, merge, join and groupby().count() but it does look horrible and spaghetti-code-ish so I am really not a fan of what I've done. Most importantly, I don't feel like I can trust my piece of code on any dataframe that I pass to the script from the command line, it doesn't seem very reproducible.

Could you help me out a bit? What's the neatest and most pythonic solution you can think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `ID` to index, then create consecutive `S*` columns, get averages per `S*` columns, compare by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) for greater like `0` and last count `True`s by `sum` :

```
df = df.set_index('ID')

#here is simplify solution for grep data by values before _
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_').str[0]

df = df.mean(axis=1, level=0).gt(0).sum(level=0)
print (df)
    S1  S2
ID        
A    2   2
B    1   1
C    1   0
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. Thank you very much! So neat. Love it.